# Getting crash while continuing conversion on speech framework ios 10

Tags: ios, swift3, speech-recognition

I am getting crash while continue talk with `speech.framework` and getting below crash of AVAudio engine getting NULL.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false:
>   nullptr == Tap()'

This is due to in some cases my `AudioEngine` getting `null`.

Here is my StartRecording function code :

```
func startRecording(){

    if recognizationTask != nil{
        recognizationTask?.cancel()
        recognizationTask = nil
    }

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do{
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeSpokenAudio)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        print("Audion session properies weren't set because of an error.")
    }

    recognizationRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()

    guard let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode as AVAudioInputNode? else {
        fatalError("Audio engine has no input node")
    }

    guard let recognizationRequest = recognizationRequest else {
        fatalError("Unable to create an SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognizationRequest object.")
    }

    recognizationRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true

    recognizationTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: recognizationRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
        var isFinal = false

        if result != nil{
            self.txtViewSiriDetecation.text = result?.bestTranscription.formattedString
            isFinal = (result?.isFinal)!
        }

        if error != nil || isFinal {
            self.audioEngine.stop()
            inputNode.removeTap(onBus:0)

            self.recognizationRequest = nil
            self.recognizationTask = nil

            self.btnSiri.isEnabled = true

        }


    })

    let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer, when) in
        self.recognizationRequest?.append(buffer)
    }

    audioEngine.prepare()

    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        print("audio engine couldn't start b'cus of an error.")
    }

    txtViewSiriDetecation.text = "Say something, I'm listening!"

}
```

How can I overcome this situation of getting NULL ?

Any one guide me on this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem too,  adding audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0) fixed it for me.

```
  fileprivate func stopRecording() {
      recordingMic.isHidden = true
      audioEngine.stop()
      audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
      recognitionRequest?.endAudio()
      recognitionTask?.cancel()

      self.detectSpeechButton.isEnabled = true
      self.detectSpeechButton.setTitle("Detect Speech", for: .normal)
      recordingMic.isHidden = true
      self.textView.isHidden = false
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Non-nil format for installTap is being passed. This should only be done when attaching to an output bus which is not connected to another node; an error will result otherwise. The tap and connection formats (if non-nil) on the specified bus should be identical. Otherwise, the latter operation will override any previously set format.